# Get records where parent id is null and replace data with records which have 'parent id'=id

Tags: mysql, database

I have table:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| ID    | parent_id   | name      | other_data  | 
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| 1     |  null       | name      | ...         |
| 2     |  null       | name1     | ...         |
| 3     |  null       | name2     | ...         |
| 4     |  2          | name1new  | ...         |
| 5     |  3          | name2new  | ...         |
| 6     |  3          | name2new2 | ...         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

And I need all records where parent_id is null. Simple query can be like:

```
    SELECT id, name
        FROM  `table` 
        WHERE  `parent_id` IS NULL 
        LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It would return 3 records:

```
 1 name;
 2 name1;
 3 name2
```

What I want is to get these 3 records but replace second two with new values from elements having parent_id as current ID (e.g. 4 row has parent_id 2 so in second row new data must come from row 4. But both: row 5 and row 6 has parent_id 3, so 3 row must have data from row 6 -- the newer one).
I need result like:

```
1 name; 
4 name1new;
6 name2new2;
```

---

SOLVED:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN  `t2`.`parent_id` is NOT NULL THEN `t2`.`id` ELSE `t1`.`id` END) as `new_id`,
(CASE WHEN  `t2`.`parent_id` is NOT NULL THEN `t2`.`name` else `t1`.`name` END) as `new_name`
FROM `table` as `t1` LEFT JOIN `table` as `t2` on (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`parent_id` AND `t2`.`some_id` = '6') WHERE `t1`.`parent_id` IS NULL;
```

THX for help @Vishal Zanzrukia

Comment: I will. But you should remove errors :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
tmp1.new_id,
tmp1.new_name
from
(select
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.ID else t1.ID end) as new_id,
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.name else t1.name end) as new_name,
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.parent_id else concat(t1.id,t1.name) end) as parent_id
    from table t1 left join table t2 on t1.ID = t2.parent_id group by new_id) tmp1
left join
(select
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.ID else t1.ID end) as new_id,
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.name else t1.name end) as new_name,
    (case when  t2.parent_id is not null then t2.parent_id else concat(t1.id,t1.name) end) as parent_id
    from table t1 left join table t2 on t1.ID = t2.parent_id group by new_id) tmp2
on (tmp1.parent_id = tmp2.parent_id and tmp1.new_id < tmp2.new_id)
where tmp2.new_id is null
;
```

Comment: I get error: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case when t2.parent_id is not null then t2.name else t1.name end as new_name fr' at line 3`

Comment: sorry for that. try now :)

Comment: Get error same. But if I use comma after new_id its ok.
but get  to mutch records: 
`1 name; 
4 name1new;
5 name2new;
6 name2new;`

Comment: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` - error

Comment: oh sorry again for syntax error :) check updated ans :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$sql="select parent_id,name from table where parent_id  IS NOT NULL  group by parent_id";
while($r= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql))){
    $sql2="update table set name='$r[name]' where ID=$r[parent_id]  and parent_id  IS NULL ";
    mysql_query($sql2);

}
```